# math(jax) in epub for ipad

Tags: epub, mathjax, ibooks

dear experts:  we would like to publish a magazine in epub format, so that it can be read on iPads.  (our creation system is now multimarkdown -> specialized post-processor -> calibre .)  the problem is that our magazine needs math.  this is not a problem on the epub viewer in ubuntu, as invoked by calibre.  it invokes mathjax just fine.  however, transfering the epub to a (net-connected) ipad (open in ibook) does not execute mathjax to display the equation.  eventually, I also want this to work in android tablets, but for now, ipads are our only target.  (iphones are too small for us, anyway.)

I do not want to graphically render the content, because I have never seen this look nice.

is there any way to create an ebook with mathjax for an ipad?  the best choice would be if there were a way to get ibooks to execute javascript?  if not, is there a tool that makes an app with ebook-reader-like functionality from html5 (incl javascript)?  (does the javascript need to be local, or can it be web-connected?)  if not, then what?

sincerely,  /iaw

Answer (score 2):

You can use MathJax in iBooks if you include a (slimmed down) MathJax installation within the ebook itself.  This is not a great solution, but it can be made to work.  See [this article](http://boolesrings.org/krautzberger/2013/01/13/how-to-include-mathjax-in-an-epub3-file-to-work-with-ibooks-and-possibly-others/) for some tips on how to do it.  It is a little out of date, but I think it should still work.

In terms of preprocessing, which I know you don't want to do, you could use MathJax to generate SVG versions of the mathematics, which look pretty good on iOS, and should render on other platforms as well, so that might be a viable option for you.

Comment: hi davide--- you assume too much.  I just want reasonable looking embedded math that rescales.  if there was a way to do a "$ makemymathuniversallyviewable < self-contained-input.html > self-contained-output.html" and then the self-contained-output.html would render and rescale nicely in borwsers and in epub, I would be even happier.  possible?

Comment: It is more complex a problem than it might seem at first.  You could probably use MathJax's SVG output to do this (it is the only one that is independent of the rendering engine).  But we don't currently have a command-line tool for this (though there are some examples of pieces of it).  Even with this, however, there are difficulties, as the SVG output doesn't reflow on changes of screen widths, so line-breaking would not work well, and equation number placement would be problematic.

Comment: thanks for the clarification and pointers.  I will experiment with the slimmed down version and see how it does.  it would be nice to have a maintained minimal-mathjax-for-epub...or better yet, have mathjax become a standard that is available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a short script in

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154644/eqnarray-math-to-svg?noredirect=1#comment353540_154644

that is a start for converting inline mathjax into inline svg.  this should work in any epub and remove the mathjax dependency.  it still has baseline problems, but it's a start.  it rescales.  hopefully someone else will pick it up and make it more robust.